# Apache with Mono not found

Tags: .net, apache, centos, mono

I installed Mono and Apache on Centos 7.
I follow this official article: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/

I copyed into var/www/html a webservice in .net (asmx).
When I try, Chrome and Mozilla display this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.cs" Class="WebService" %>
```

Why do I only see the source code of the webservice.asmx file?
I followed step by step all the instructions, but it does not work.
I can only view ASMX sites using XSP

Comment: I am not sure whether 'regex' forum is right avenue for this question

Comment: At this moment you should use ASP.NET Core on CentOS, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/web/aspnet-hello-world-tutorial What you attempted to use are years old and should be marked as obsolete.